# add name property to HTML::_(image..)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am try to modify the mod language of joomla.

I want to show the image of the flag and the name of the language at the end, how to do that... I dont find the parameters of html::_('image')

```
<?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/'.$language->image.'.png', $language->title_native, array('title'=>$language->title_native), true);?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef);?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view how to pass parameters to the `JHtml::_('image')` method here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/html/html.php#L567